# Sorting in tastypie for non-orm(mongodb)

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have constructed an django-tastypie api.It returns data when i hit the url.
I want the data to be sorted based on  date. The problem is its a character field

Resource Code:

```
class myResource(Resource):
  date = fields.CharField(attribute='date', default=None)
  time = fields.CharField(attribute='time', default=None)
  myid = fields.FloatField(attribute='newsid', default=None)

  class Meta:
    resource_name = 'data'
    object_class = dict2obj

  def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    bundle = []

    #get_data fetches data from mongodb

    content = self.get_data()

    #content is a dict    

    for key, value in content.items():
      value['myid'] = key
      bundle.append(dict2obj(value))

    #bundle is a list

    return bundle
```

Url Hit Returns:

```
    [{
        date: "2013-09-24 08:56:00.000",
        myid: 266131,
        time: "08:56"
    },
    {
        date: "2013-09-24 09:43:00.000",
        myid: 266151,
        resource_uri: "/api/eboss/news/266151/"

    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `dict2obj`, but if `date` and `time` are really date and time, then using `tastypie.fields.DateField` and `tastypie.fields.TimeField` respectively are more appropriate.

To do sorting, You can override `apply_sorting(obj_list, options=None)` function, where `options` is dictionary containing query parameters (GET method).